# Hide Minimap/Scrollbar in Sublime Text

Tags: scrollbar, sublimetext3

How do you hide the large vertical scrollbar on the right side of Sublime Text 3?
The current (default) scrollbar shows a preview of the document, and I would like to remove it. Is this possible?

Sublime Text version 3, macOS Sierra.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, just go to the View menu -> Hide Minimap and the minimap part of the scrollbar on the right hand side will be hidden.